# How to annotate the return type of python function to be exactly the same as one of the arguments?

Tags: python, python-typing

How to change annotations in the `action` method below, to make sure that both `View` and `Action` are inner classes of the same class inheriting from `Table`?

```py
from __future__ import annotations


class Player:
    def action(self, table_view: Table.View) -> Table.Action:
        ...


class Table:
    class View:
        ...

    class Action:
        ...
```

So for example, if I will make a subclass `class LimitTable(Table)` and pass instance of `LimitTable.View` as an argument to `action` method, I want to make sure the return type will also be `LimitTable.Action`.

I know I should use `typing.TypeVar` in some way, but after reading python docs and corresponding PEPs and browsing all questions about it here, I still have no clue how to do it.

Comment: You might consider not defining nested classes in the first place.

Comment: I don’t think “is a nested class of” is a relationship that typings can express. (It doesn’t even have any meaning in the language, really.)

Comment: @chepner Would it not complicate the code even more if I made them top level classes and have to somehow describe which subclasses of View and Action corresponds to which subclasses of Table?

Comment: @skrzacik320 Not really, because subclassing `Table` doesn't automatically create new subclasses of `View` or `Action`.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, but I find it very counter intuitive. Both View and Action are closely related to the Table, they don't make any sense outside of it. Also why forcing user to write `import LimitTable, LimitTableView, LimitTableAction` instead of simply `import LimitTable`?

Comment: One option would be to parameterize `View` by the kind of table, and have `Table` provide a class method that returns the correct type of view. There's not enough detail in your question to provide a good example implementation, but nested class definitions simply aren't a common thing in Python.

Comment: @chepner The implementation of `Table` doesn't really matter for my question. And I suspect it would actually make it harder to answer it if I wrote it your way since types relationship couldn't be inferred before runtime.

Comment: Given an instance of `Whatever.View`, how are you getting a reference to `Whatever` in order to produce `Whatever.Action`?

Comment: @chepner Set of `Whatever.Action` objects is a property of `Whatever.View` instance passed to `action` method.

Comment: Yes, but you have to set that explicitly, no? It's not something you get for "free" because you defined `View` inside `Table`.

Comment: @chepner I have a method `create_view(self, ...)` in `Table` class that creates set of `self.Action` objects and returns `self.View` object with reference to this set. Player should not be able to access `Table` instance since it stores some data he should not be able to reach.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can come is to define a type variable `T` which is bounded by `Table`:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bounded=Table)
```

and use that in place of `Table` in your type hints:

```
class Player:
    def action(self, table_view: T.View) -> T.Action:
        ...
```

This, however, does not not prevent `action` from taking a `Table.View` as an argument and returning a `LimitedTable.Action`; this is a known issue, acknowledged in [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound):

> Unfortunately, addressing this would require introducing a much more powerful and also much more complicated concept, F-bounded polymorphism. We may revisit this in the future.

The other issue (one I presume you have taken care of, but worth pointing out) is that you still need some way, given an instance of `Table.View`, to identify the correct `Action` class for the return type. You don't have an instance of `Table` available so that you can use something like `type(table_view).Action`.